# Extract the number after the decimal ponit in c#

Tags: c#

I should write a program that the input is double (variable called money), and I should print separately the digits before the decimal point and the digits after.
for example:

for the input: 36.5 should print: `The number before the decimal point is: 36 The number after decimal point is: 5`

for the input: 25.4 should print: `The number before the decimal point is: 24 The number after decimal point is: 4`

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter money:");
            double money = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int numBeforePoint = (int)money;
            double numAfterPoint = (money - (int)money)*10;
            Console.WriteLine("The number beforethe decimal point is: {0}. the number after the decimal point is: {1}",numBeforePoint,numAfterPoint);
```

If I enter `25.4` it prints: `The number before the decimal point is: 24 The number after decimal point is: 3.9999999`

I don't want `3.999999` I want `4`

Comment: You shouldn't use `double` for financial values - use `decimal`. Floating-point types are for scientific calculations. Different types have different precision.

Comment: A hacky solution - You could use math.round...

Comment: @AGrammerPro Not hacky at all. Math.Round is commonly used to correct floating point precision errors such as this.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I mean it is 'hacky' because he should not be using a double. lack of wording on my part!

Comment: Why use any math types at all? All you care about is the presence of a certain character in the input. Treat it as a string all along and you don't have to worry about any sort of rounding errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) to represent numeric types, rather than `double`s - it's what they were designed for!

You've been the victim of a floating point error, where the value you're assigning to a floating point value can't be exactly represented with its precision (the `.999...` you get is the closest value it *can* represent).

`decimal`s have a lower range than `double`s, but much higher precision - this means they're more likely to be able to represent the values you're assigning. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) or the linked `decimal` documentation page for more details.

Note that a more conventional way of getting the decimal part involves [`Math.Truncate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf(v=vs.110).aspx) (which by the way will work for negative values as well):

```
decimal numAfterPoint = (money - Math.Truncate(money))*10;
```

Comment: While true; could you discuss why that type would solve this problem?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Whoops, you caught me mid-edit!

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to use the string representation of the decimal, and use substring before and after the index of '.'

Something like this:

```
string money = Console.ReadLine();
int decimalIndex = money.IndexOf('.');
string numBeforePoint = money.Substring(0, decimalIndex);
string numAfterPoint = money.Substring(decimalIndex + 1);
```

Then you can parse the string representations as needed.

Comment: Not all languages use the `.` as the fraction separator. In some languages, it's `,` and there may be others I'm not aware of.

Comment: I'm aware, but the poster implied a period would be the separator.

Comment: The poster probably doesn't realize that it makes a difference.

Comment: @xxbbcc, no that's wrong. `,` is thousand separator and not floating point separator. `.` is universal decimal separator

Comment: @Rahul Look up formatting settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
static string Foo(double d)
        {
            var str = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');
            var left = str[0];
            var right = str[1];
            return $"The number before the decimal point is: {left} The number after decimal point is: {right}";
        }
```

Comment: Not all languages use the `.` as the fraction separator. In some languages, it's `,` and there may be others I'm not aware of.

Comment: Good point. (Pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

public static string GetDecimalRemainder(double d)
{
    return d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.').Last();
{
```

Using LINQ is much more convenient in my opinion.